# hazelcast mapstore not persisted with multiple members

Tags: spring, jpa, apache-camel, hazelcast

I am having a strange problem using MapStore and Hazelcast. I have implemented a MapStore which persist to a database. When I start my hazelcast application I have two members. When my client program call map.put(key, object) it will only be stored if it is on member-1 when is is on member-2 the entry is not persisted. See the screenshot below. My database table has 5 records but i am missing the 7 records from 5702 member. I expected to have 12 record in my database table. What is wrong ?

[image]

Here is my mapstore config, it is in applicationContext because i use spring, jpa, hibernate

```
    <!--  Mapstores -->
<bean id="customerMap" class="nl.ict.psa.ocr.hazelcast.mapstores.CustomerMapStore"/>

<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>

        <hz:management-center enabled="true" url="http://localhost:6060/mancenter"/>

        <hz:network port="${hz.network.port}" port-auto-increment="${hz.port.autoincrement}">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="true" />
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>

        <hz:map name="customer" read-backup-data="true">
            <hz:map-store write-coalescing="true" enabled="true" write-delay-seconds="${hz.write.delay.seconds}"
                          initial-mode="LAZY"
                          implementation="customerMap"/>
        </hz:map>

    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

port-auto-increment = false, write-delay-seconds = 0

Thanks

J

Comment: Is the config on both nodes?

Comment: I am starting the application on one server and it creates two members

Comment: but have both members the same configuration? From what you describe it sounds like the second member doesn't know about the mapstore configuration.

Comment: I am using camel with hazelcast and it starts to members, only on the first member the mapstore is ok, the second member does not cal my mapstore.

Comment: As I said you need to make sure the configuration for the mapstore is available on both members. I'm not familiar with the Camel integration, therefore I cannot explain how to do this, sorry. Guess you need to ask the Camel guys (maybe add the tag to the question).